# Using loops to display specific arraylist objects

Tags: java

So I need to display certain elements in an arraylist that have an integer value of over 7. So far I've written this but I'm struggling to make it work. Can anyone help?

```
public Diary()
{
    jobname = new ArrayList<Job>();
}


public void priority ()
{
    int index = 0;
    while (index < jobname.size ()) {
        Job jobName = jobname.get (index);
        index ++;
        //if (jobname.get (priority)) {
        //    System.out.println (jobname);
        //}
    }
}
```

This is the Job class that is referred to by the Diary.

```
public Job(String job, int priorityNum, String day) 
{
    if (priority < 0 || priority > 10) {
        priority = 0;
    }
    else {
        priority = priorityNum;
    }
    jobname = job;
    dueDay = day;
}

public boolean isUrgent()
{
    return priority > 7;
}


public String toString ()
{
   String s = "";
   s += "Job = " + jobname + " \n";
   s += "Day Due = " + dueDay + " \n";
   s += "Priority = " + priority + " \n";

   return s;
}
```

Comment: This code does not compile. Also, what's a Job?

Comment: Please show [mcve] that explains what `Job` is.

Comment: Sorry I didnt include the entire code, should I add the whole thing? The job is the other class it calls the object from

Comment: @Bradeurs you most certainly must

Comment: Does your 'get' method inside the 'if' return a 'Boolean'? I think you're missing the actual comparation of the priority... like 'if (jobname.get(priority) > 7)'

Comment: From where does the "priority" variable comes inside the method. Please check.

Comment: @r1verside wait, he's going to show the rest of the code soon

Comment: Abstract your mind! Also I have to say the increment of your while control variable 'index' should be the last line before the closing brace of the loop. For the shake of readability.

Comment: @Bradeurs this doesn't show all of the `Job` class

Comment: Alright thank you, I think I included all the relevant code. It calls the priority from the other class, and thank you I'll move the index to the bottom

Comment: @ItamarGreen Oh the entire job class? Would that not be too much?

Comment: @Bradeurs just the functions that you are using

Comment: @Bradeurs no wait. Don't post it... I was wrong

Comment: @ItamarGreen Oh, I tried to include some more to go off anyway, if thats all relevent and what you need?

Comment: @Bradeurs I get it. answered your question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your situation the best option would be "for each" loop.
It would look like that:

```
for(Job job: jobname)
{
   if(job.isUrgent()) System.out.println(job);    
}
```

Comment: What is `getPriority()`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code to the following:

```
public void priority ()
{
    foreach(Job job : jobname){
        if (job.getPriority() > 7) {
            System.out.println (job);
        }
    }
}
```

Secondly, add `getPriority()` in the `Job` class that would return the value of `priority`:

```
public String getPriority(){
    return this.priority; 
}
```

Comment: Hia thanks for your help, but I get the error "non-static method getPriority() cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: No and unfortunately I cant make it static

Comment: I swapped the code I had with the code you sent me, I also added the getPriority to the job class and it produced that error